# Maven - How to run 2 java files from different packages inside src/test/java using Annotations

Tags: java, maven, selenium, package

In My Project,

I have created 2 different packages inside /src/test/java, as both packages classes has different functionality and falls under same project.

When i try to do "Run As-> Maven Test" only the Class inside First Package is executing. Java Class in other package is not executing.

Kindly do the needful please.

Thanks in Advance.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.brocade</groupId>
    <artifactId>Vision</artifactId>
    <version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>

        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <!--first class-->
          <execution>
            <id>Build-A</id>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <mainClass>test.java.com.br.Vision.Direct_Launch_Test</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
              <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>dependencies-jar</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
              <finalName>FirstClass.jar</finalName>
            </configuration>
          </execution>

          <!--first class-->
          <execution>
            <id>Build-B</id>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <mainClass>test.java.com.br.SupportSaveUploade.To_Upload_Support_Save</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
              <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>dependencies-jar</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
              <finalName>SecondClass.jar</finalName>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jdk.version>1.8.0_45</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

    </properties>
```

Comment: First within and IDE you should use IDE to run the tests....What I don't understand why do you need those different test classes as jar's ? It sound like those package contain integration tests ? If so should use separate modules for such things..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifically for maven, you can use multiple [execution](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag) tag and configure multiple `<mainClass>` in your `pom.xml`

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>

        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <!--first class-->
          <execution>
            <id>Build-A</id>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <mainClass>test.java.FirstClass</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
              <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>dependencies-jar</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
              <finalName>FirstClass.jar</finalName>
            </configuration>
          </execution>

          <!--second class-->
          <execution>
            <id>Build-B</id>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <mainClass>test.java.SecondClass</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
              <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>dependencies-jar</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
              <finalName>SecondClass.jar</finalName>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you please explain me little brief, i dont have <build> tag in pom, can i add it as new? 
Sorry am new to this

Comment: Yes you can add. Google some sample `pom.xml` files and see their content.

Comment: I have tried this, by changing the <MainClass> with my class names, but it didntwork

Comment: I have posted my pom.xml for reference.. can you please help me on this.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
src/test/java
package1: com.br.ServiceVision
Class: Direct_Launch_Test
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
package2 com.br.SupportSaveUploade
Class: .To_Upload_Support_Save